# How Javascript strings are encoded in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome, windbg

I am analyzing via WinDbg the memory address space of Chrome.
Like I did with other processes, I need to extract all the strings that are currently allocated in memory.

To do that I am using WinDbg as a non-invasive debugger and the command

```
s -u 0x0 L?0xffffffff "string"
```

if unicode, and

```
s -a 0x0 L?0xffffffff "string"
```

if asci.

However, it looks like I miss all the strings that are allocated as javascript string objects. This makes me think that in V8 (the chrome engine) the encoding is different, and thus the byte representation of my search string is different too.

Any idea on how does it work? I've been diving into the V8 documentation for a while, but without any result so far :(

Comment: This is a total guess (it's not my area of expertise at all), but doesn't Chrome specifically spawn separate processes for each page's js runtime? I.e. the strings might show up in the memory of a process spawned by Chrome rather than Chrome itself

Comment: True, but I was checking all its processes at the same time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in V8 are not always stored as a sequence of characters, they can also be stored as ConsString, Lisp-like. You can check the actual C++ structures used in [V8 sources](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/objects.h).